# how to connect to projector in Windows 7 on Mac Pro

Tags: windows-7, mac, projector

I use windows 7 in Macbook Pro. and bought a VGA Adapter, however, the projector can not detect my computer, anyone has the idea how to set it up to connect to the projector?

Comment: You shouldn't have a problem.  Have you verified the adapter works with another monitor?

Comment: other computer works ok with this monitor